# Timer frequency calculation for UNO/Atmega328

Tags: interrupt, timers

I must be overwrought or something... I just can't get the calculation of the timer frequency right. I have a 16 MHz crystal on the Atmega328. I want 1 kHz timer interrupt rate. So I chose prescaler = 64 and counter top = 249, that is

fTimer = fCPU/prescaler/(top+1) = 16 MHz/64/250 = 1 kHz

But my oscilloscope shows 2 kHz... !? Why?

I have read [Timer2 Compare Interrupt not working as expected](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/53298/timer2-compare-interrupt-not-working-as-expected) but the accepted answer doesn't make it better. There the frequency is half as high whereas mine is twice as high as expected.

Code:

```
const int signalLED = 1; //14;

void setup() 
{
  pinMode(signalLED, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(signalLED, LOW);

  TCCR2A = 0; // set TCCR2A register to 0
  TCCR2B = 0; // set TCCR2B register to 0
  TCNT2  = 0; // reset counter
  OCR2A = 249; // top value in CTC mode
  TCCR2A |= (1 << WGM21); // enable timer2 CTC mode
  TCCR2B |= (1 << CS21) | (1 << CS20); // 1:64 prescaling for timer 2
  TIMSK2 |= (1 << OCIE2A); // enable timer2 compare interrupt
  sei(); // allow interrupts
}

ISR(TIMER2_COMPA_vect) 
{
  // generate peak
  digitalWrite(signalLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(signalLED, LOW);
}

void loop() 
{
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment:

```
TCCR2B |= (1 << CS21) | (1 << CS20); // 1:64 prescaling for timer 2
```

doesn't match the actual setting (= 1/32)

Also there are some issues with setting Timer2 CTC mode, it's better to set mode, then OCR2A + TCNT2 + interrupts and then Prescaler to start the timer. It behaves as there is OCR2A=0, so the frequency is much higher than expected.

Comment: That was the problem. I just mixed up the prescaler setting specs of Timer1 with those of Timer2. For Timer1 CS11|CS10 is 64. I knew that standing up too early wouldn't be good for me... ;-)